# Select pair that is used for another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

| ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 1111 |
| 222 | 2222 |

| ID1 | ID2 | events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1111 | aaaa |
| 222 | 2222 | bbbb |
| 333 | 3333 | cccc |
| 444 | 4444 | dddd |

How to get all rows from second table where the ID pair is from first table.
The result should return

| ID1 | ID2 | events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1111 | aaaa |
| 222 | 2222 | bbbb |

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1
              from table1 t1
              where t1.id1 = t2.id1 and t1.id2 = t2.id2
             );
```

Note that a `join` can return duplicate rows, if `table1` has duplicates.  `Exists` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

a simple join:

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
join table1 t1
  on t1.ID1 = t2.ID1
  and t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
```